# Java Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, linux, x11, xserver

I have a script using java to connect to display X11 in the port 10.0 at localhost

but i get always this error

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:62)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:142)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:112)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:849)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:841)
    at ij.io.Opener.openJpegOrGif(Opener.java:367)
    at ij.io.Opener.openImage(Opener.java:220)
    at ij.io.Opener.openImage(Opener.java:249)
    at ij.io.Opener.open(Opener.java:116)
    at ij.IJ.open(IJ.java:1112)
    at ij.macro.Functions.open(Functions.java:2006)
    at ij.macro.Functions.doFunction(Functions.java:129)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doStatement(Interpreter.java:205)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doBlock(Interpreter.java:515)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.runUserFunction(Interpreter.java:278)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.getFactor(Interpreter.java:1200)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.getTerm(Interpreter.java:1162)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.getExpression(Interpreter.java:1145)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.getBooleanExpression(Interpreter.java:881)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.getLogicalExpression(Interpreter.java:857)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.getBoolean(Interpreter.java:850)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doIf(Interpreter.java:829)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doStatement(Interpreter.java:217)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doBlock(Interpreter.java:515)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doStatement(Interpreter.java:241)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doIf(Interpreter.java:831)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doStatement(Interpreter.java:217)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.doStatements(Interpreter.java:195)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:99)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:65)
    at ij.macro.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:75)
    at ij.plugin.Macro_Runner.runMacro(Macro_Runner.java:127)
    at ij.plugin.Macro_Runner.runMacroFile(Macro_Runner.java:112)
    at ij.IJ.runMacroFile(IJ.java:103)
    at ij.ImageJ.main(ImageJ.java:517)
```

I have tried everything to solve this problem like :

```
export DISPLAY=:10.0
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

I tried also the port 0.0 but i get always the same error

after trying xhost

```
xhost +local:all
xhost:  unable to open display ""
xhost:  unable to open display ":10.0"
```

how can i fix this
i thought that the X Server is not runing so i tried `startx` its says its runing at that port

my system is Ubuntu server edition 10.04

Comment: If also using a VNC viewer via ssh:  after modifying the `xhost` access list, it is necessary to reopen the SSH connection.  At least on my current setup (VNC to Debian), I infer that it needs to get an updated xhost access list.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This command helped me to solve the problem:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: `unset DISPLAY` helped me (with `export DISPLAY=:0` I got the error `Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0'`

Comment: well sometime - it won't work on linux then its good to install Xvfb with apt and run it on any screen like: Xvfb :1 and then set variable in build phase -- export DISPLAY=:1 --> this perfectly works.

Comment: Please, read: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607777/what-display-settings-needed-for-running-sh-installer-for-java-7-ee-sdk-on-mac

Answer (score 74):

You need to specify the [`-Djava.awt.headless=true`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) parameter at startup time.

Comment: Thanks alot but where i have to specify this exactly ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.awt.He          adlessException
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:1          73)

Comment: Are you running a security manager? If so, you maybe have to grant permission to.

Comment: thanks the problem was that the X Server is running in another port

Comment: i got the same problem on another server and its because the driver

Comment: This solved my problem with a Jenkins build. It just suddenly STOPPED working, and adding this flag to the maven command line fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. 

In Jenkins -> Build -> Goals and options -> -Djava.awt.headless=true test 

In my case
clean compile  -Djava.awt.headless=true test

Comment: The asker's program wants to do `ij.io.Opener.openJpegOrGif`, we can guess that probably requires a GUI. So headless would result in another error: `java.awt.HeadlessException`.

Comment: with this true - i got error: java.awt.AWTException: headless environment

Comment: This prevents the error, but now the GUI popup that is supposed to go to my main display just does not exist at all...

Answer (score 53):

Remove the DISPLAY variable

```
unset DISPLAY
```

This helps in most cases (e.g. starting application servers or other java based tools) and avoids to modify all that many command lines.

It can also be comfortable to add it to the .bash_profile for a dedicated app-server/tools user.

Comment: it didn't help me at all. I got this: AWT Can't connect to X11 window server using...

Comment: If your app uses awt then you must set DISPLAY correctly. This is for apps not using awt.

Comment: When playing around with this, make sure you restart mobaXterm after adding the unset command in your bashfile. Since the Display variable will be set from before and just running your bash file won't change that.

Comment: This works when I use Putty + Xming Server:0.0. Unfortunately, I have the same error when using wsl2. I haven`t tried mobaXterm, but, you need to restart Xming after adding the unset command as well

Answer (score 30):

I think you are working in sudo mode.Please checkout to the user mode and try again

Comment: This was my problem as well. Seems odd to not be able to run as root though, right?

Comment: Why I can't use sudo ?

Comment: @javajavajava yup

Comment: Worked for me.. think the X11 server can only be started by the owner of the current session in my case root

Comment: Seems the same problem for me. Had to start `Xvfb` from out my gitlab pipeline, could not do that in the docker image itself.

Answer (score 9):

In case anybody trying to run the automated unit tests via maven-surefire-plugin on CI(jenkins,..), and getting the above mentioned error, be sure to update your surefire plugin configuration :

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
     <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: how to do it in gradle and also how to set the property value in it.

Answer (score 8):

This will fix it:

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true $Your_program
```

Comment: Did not fix mine

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you.  I was getting the error because I'm using poi.

Answer (score 7):

For me logging in as **-Y** instead of -X worked.

In case you've got untrusted X11 as shown below, then try -Y flag instead (if you trust the host):

**Warning**: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to export display using su and it still doesn't work.
This is what worked for me. Try X11 forwarding for sudo users.

Connect the remote host using the -X option with ssh.

```
# ssh -X root@remote-host
```

Now list the coockie set for the current user.

```
# xauth list $DISPLAY
    node01.thegeekdiary.com/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  dacbc5765ec54a1d7115a172147866aa
# echo $DSIPLAY
    localhost:10.0
```

Switch to another user account using sudo. Add the cookie from the command output above to the sudo user.

```
# sudo su - [user]
# xauth add node01.thegeekdiary.com/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  dacbc5765ec54a1d7115a172147866aa
```

Export the display from step 2 again for the sudo user. Try the command xclock to verify if the x client applications are working as expected.

```
# export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

source: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-set-x11-forwarding-export-remote-display-for-users-who-switch-accounts-using-sudo/

Answer (score 6):

This fixed my problem

```
xhost +
```

but Be aware that `xhost +` completely deactivates authentication and allows everyone to access all application on your screen.

`xhost +si:localuser:root` seems to work similar with proper authentication.

Answer (score 4):

First: start XQuartz

Second: ssh -X user@ip_address

...: start your process

if you ssh and then start XQuartz you will get that error

Answer (score 3):

After several days of futile effort of installing glassfish on raspberry pi 2 with headless fedora 22, Below worked for me without a hitch

```
 unset DISPLAY
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar glassfissh-installer-v2ur2-b04-linux.jar
```

got my help from [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/error-can-t-connect-to-x11-window-server-is-reported-during-server-startup-226788690.html)

Answer (score 3):

First do this either in Build Phase of Jenkins if using or set in /etc/profile:

```
unset DISPLAY
export DISPLAY=:0
```

then set this property either in java code or using maven:
-Djava.awt.headless=false

Answer (score 2):

I was using Xming and got similar error. Following steps were taken to fix the issue:

1. In Xming launch check the box no access control.
2. In putty ran the following command: `DISPLAY=XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:0.0; export DISPLAY`

Replace `XXX.XXX.XXX.XX` with your IP address.

Comment: I am in the same configuration, however it didn't work. I needed to add the IP executing X11 in X0.hosts file

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I just logout and login with xorg!

Comment: export DISPLAY=:0 or export DISPLAY=:1 did not work for me. Logging out and logging in solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

check whether `$DISPLAY` variable is set or not, with the below command:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

if the display variable is not set, run the below command to set, (even if it is set, you can have below one for your session)

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

in [putty](/questions/tagged/putty) also have the `x` display location as `:0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Michael-O gave useful approach to solve the problem. Another way to solve this is by starting the server with Putty Console.

Comment: can you maybe explain a Little more how that would work? (I have never used putty)

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was no space left in my machine and I faced the same issue.
Some times it could be the space issue. Check the space in your Linux/Unix environment and make sure your machine have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 17.10
Install X virtual frame buffer (xvfb)

```
apt install xvfb
```

And added these lines to the /etc/profile file...

```
# Start the X virtual frame buffer (Xvfb)
if [ -f /usr/X11R6/bin/Xvfb ]; then
/usr/X11R6/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1366x768x32
fi

# Set the DISPLAY variable for the X virtual frame buffer (Xvfb)
export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0
```

Comment: Now I just get "Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:1.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable." on Ubuntu 16.04. The Xvfb binary now seems to be located at /usr/bin, not /usr/X11R6/bin, but gives me "Couldn't add screen 0 (EE)".

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by logging in using Xorg. By default, I have used Wayland. It looks like Wayland eliminates most of the design flaws of the Xorg it has its own issues.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on the Linux server I was working on. Connecting java to a X11 display worked on the head node, but not on any other. After contacting the administrator, it turned out that the current version of our job-scheduling system (SLURM) did not support X11 forwarding. They had to update SLURM (newer versions of SLURM support it) for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

the only way i got it to work was running the script with a template. e.g. sudo ./glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh -s template

This installs Glassfish in Silent Mode. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2427/ghmva.html

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same error with you when i run the jconsole command at remote. I want to modify a parameter at jconsole that run on a remote Linux host, i can login the host use the secureCRT, the terminal throw this error information. Fortunately, when use the Putty, it's ok. Weird....

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error in Hudson, try to remove the .java directory from your home directory, it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're triggering your code from Jenkins, enabling the option "Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after" might help. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

change to a another user and try except root. it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just didn't log out of root before running ./studio.sh All set.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was not related to the DISPLAY port. I was trying to load an XML into Windchill (a PLM-software) and received only the above error on the terminal. In a logfile I found the report that **my XML-file was corrupt**. Maybe someone has a similar problem and can use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mine issue was with the firewall. Disabled it temporarily.

[EDIT] And, the server hostname was pointing to another IP. Set it to simply localserver. `strace xclock` helped to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the above worked, but after long search this worked for me.

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. export localhost:1
2. -Djava.awt.headless=true

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have this exact error when I was launching the Jetbrains IDEs, such as Pycharm, IntelliJ IDEA...

I typed this in the same terminal that I was using to start the IDE to solve the problem:

```bash
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Then I started the IDE from the same terminal issuing the command `pycharm` and it worked like a charm.

The output of both IDEs was:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

run below cmd fixed my issue. works for my case

`unset DISPLAY`

Answer (score -1):

If you start application on a remote server while logged in by ssh then another way would be to start ssh with `-x` parameter or add `ForwardX11 no` in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. In this case ssh will not create environment variable DISPLAY.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the problem was that *xorg-x11-xauth* wasn't installed. I installed it and then it worked.

The packages that I have now are:

- *libX11-common-1.6.3-2.el6.noarch*
- *libX11-1.6.3-2.el6.i686*
- *libX11-1.6.3-2.el6.x86_64*
- *xorg-x11-drv-ati-firware-7.6.1-2.el6.noarch*
- *xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-1.el6.x86_64*