# java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I am trying to run my java app on ubuntu server, but i constantly receive this error:
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server. I set the DISPLAY variable to :0.0 but that didn't help. In the X11 log file i got these error messages:
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) intel(0): No kernel modesetting driver detected.
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.

Comment: I'm wondering if [su] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: duplicate? have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t/13809464#13809464

Answer (score 2):

Use

java -Djava.awt.headless=true …

to start without connecting to the X server. This (and other tips) are found in

http://javatechniques.com/blog/linux-x11-libraries-for-headless-mode/