# What DISPLAY settings needed for running .sh installer for Java 7 EE SDK on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, shell, installation, environment-variables

When I attempt to run the shell...

From the install manual: Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 SDK -
Installation Instructions

> **Solaris, Linux, and Mac OS X systems:**
>
> If necessary, grant execute permissions to the distribution file:
>   chmod +x ./ distribution-filename
>
> At the command prompt, type: sh ./ distribution-filename

It says it needs the DISPLAY variable set - what do I need to set it to?

```
a12-macmini-02:Downloads rdavis$ ./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh 
This program requires DISPLAY environment variable to be set.
Please re-run after assigning an appropriate value to DISPLAY.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> It says it needs the DISPLAY variable set - what do I need to set it
>   to?

Instead of saying:

```
./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh
```

say:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh
```

Alternatively, you could get the tarball installer instead and extract it to the desired location.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know there was a tarball installer - it doesn't seem to be in an obvious place. The main downloads page is here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html and the specific download page is here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html no sign or a tarball. Nice to know there might be one, but why would they offer a choice? Surely one kind of installer should be sufficient? Or are they needed owing to the user's environment restrictions?

Comment: @therobyouknow Did you see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)?

Comment: That's for SE which might suffice but I was originally looking for EE.

Comment: @therobyouknow EE isn't too far away: see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @devnull but what do you mean 'not too far away' - not sure where to look on that page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html

Comment: @therobyouknow You need to navigate to the [downloads tab](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html).

Comment: `DISPLAY=:0 ./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh` worked - I ran it as root user as well (if that helped, comments welcome), so I'm +1ing and accepting your answer. Just as an aside, on your last comment: "You need to navigate to the downloads tab." - yes, I have already been to that page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html and can't see other format of download offered apart from .sh my screen shot of the page here: http://i42.tinypic.com/2igdj.png

Comment: @therobyouknow Didn't realize that they don't make the tarball installer available for JAVA EE.