# Exception in base installation of the Oracle DB EE 19c/18c

Tags: java, oracle

I have installed the Oracle DB 18c EE from the Oracle repository.
After an installation with all preinstallations I have the next exception after starting the DBCA:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./dbca
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(LookUtils.java:484)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(LookUtils.java:249)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:135)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1874)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:582)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:940)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:198)
    at oracle.assistants.common.base.driver.AssistantApplication.startup(AssistantApplication.java:328)
    at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigurator.startup(DBConfigurator.java:378)
    at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigurator.main(DBConfigurator.java:513)
```

But as the root it is not happened. But the DBCA must be run by the oracle db user.
I've added the oracle user to the wheel group on the CentOS (sudo users).
How Can I solve the problem?

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am using the Oracle JDK for Linux (.rpm). It is normally started as root (displayed, but require starting with oracle user).

Comment: Well then, bad news - you're screwed. :-( OpenJDK doesn't include the Java AWT, which the DBCA apparently uses. See Christian Bongiorno's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131855/could-not-initialize-class-sun-awt-x11graphicsenvironment-on-solaris). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working after an logining in the linux with the oracle user. sudo -u oracle is an error.