# Cannot solve Java Sun error when installing Xilinx in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x11, ubuntu-20.04, xilinx

I recently made a post detailing an issue with creating a RedPitaya ecosystem on my Windows 11 laptop and wanted to see if my Windows 10 desktop had anymore luck.

After installing Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa) via Microsoft Store, I faked my OS to 18.04.4 (Bionic Beaver) which is required to avoid issues with Xilinx installer. I attempted to install Xilinx Unified 2020.1 via

```
chmod +x ./Xilinx_Unified_2020.1_0602_1208_Lin64.bin
sudo ./Xilinx_Unified_2020.1_0602_1208_Lin64.bin
```

but I ran into this common error:

```
ERROR: Installer could not be started.
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
java.awt.HeadlessException:
```

Following other StackOverflow answers (namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131855/could-not-initialize-class-sun-awt-x11graphicsenvironment-on-solaris)), I set my `DISPLAY` variable to `localhost:0.0`, `:0.0`, `:0`, and unset it, all of which resulted in the following error message:

```
ERROR: Installer could not be started. Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.initGC(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at h.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.xilinx.installer.gui.F.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.xilinx.installer.gui.InstallerGUI.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.xilinx.installer.gui.InstallerGUI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.xilinx.installer.api.InstallerLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

When installing Xilinx on my laptop I kept a record of what solved my errors, and I wrote that installing OpenJDK via

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

solved my issue, but on my desktop this is not the case. I have attempted with several versions of Java (including Java 8, 17, and 19) from both OpenJDK and Oracle, and I have installed them by either .tar.gz files, repositories, or terminal install commands.

Currently I am running

```
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and receiving the error message.

Any help using OpenJDK or Oracle is appreciated.

I am running x64 Windows 10 Home 21H2, OS Build 19044.2251, and I am unable to update to Windows 11 (error code 0xc1900101). I have also installed Ubuntu through Windows Subsystem for Linux, and that has not resulted in any different results.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install Vitis/Vivado in a WSL environment by following this guide (the main steps of which I will leave at the end in case the link breaks):
https://cadhut.com/2020/09/08/how-to-install-vivado-vitis-using-just-the-command-line/

The issue (I believe) is that the installer is trying to launch its GUI, but cannot because WSL does not support that like a native Ubuntu install would. **NOTE** I am fairly certain that installing on the CLI like this will not allow you to launch the Vitis/vivado GUIs even if you are successful, so if you need those, you likely want to look at dual booting a native Ubuntu install of the correct version OR installing Xilinx tools in a Linux VM (I have used oracle VMWare for this in the past with success). The point of installing in WSL for me was to run builds in batch mode/via CLI and scripts.

Also; I am not sure what you mean by 'faking' your OS version, but for the most part those warnings about supported OS can be ignored if you're willing to occasionally troubleshoot python version issues and such. AFAIK it should still let you install on an unsupported OS. The more important requirement is installing all the required packages and tools.

Outlined steps from linked guide (should be enough to get someone started):

```
#Extract installer files 
tar -zxvf <filename>.tar.gz
#Generate install config (will need to press 1 during this step)
./xsetup -b ConfigGen
#Launch installer with required args 
./xsetup --a XilinxEULA,3rdPartyEULA,WebTalkTerms -b Install -c /home/<user>/.Xilinx/install_config.txt
```

Comment: I actually discovered the batch install yesterday and attempted to use it to install without having the GUI run (the GUI ran on my Win11 laptop thanks to its WSLg). I ran into an issue getting the authentication code to be recognized within batch mode, although I extracted the installer with another command, not tar, so that could be the case.

I was planning on dual booting Win10 (my desktop fails Win11 update for some reason) and an Ubuntu install on an empty SSD, so I will follow the method you linked and if that doesn’t work then dual boot may be only option. Thank you!