# Can't connect to X11 window server

Tags: java, ubuntu, x11

I'm trying to run a Java application on Xubuntu 14.04, but I always get

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:119)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:868)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:860)
```

echo $DISPLAY returns :0.0

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you running an X server? That is, is there one for it to connect to?

Comment: I'm a linux beginner, but I've just installed Xubuntu distro (with desktop), so I assume there is a X server running.

Comment: Try one of advises from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t

Comment: Does `echo $DISPLAY` return "0.0" or ":0.0"? It _should_ return the latter.

Comment: Setting system property java.awt.headless to true helps but then I get java.awt.HeadlessException. It's not the solution for me. I need headfull JVM.

Comment: Just checking - you're actually working on a display, keyboard, mouse, etc __directly__ connected to the computer?

Comment: Are you launching this from a shell? Do other X programs (try `xterm`) work when attempted from the same place?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's standard desktop Xubuntu distro.

Comment: @AndrewMedico xterm works (at least it opens a terminal), my application is a J2EE, so I launch the Tomcat ($ sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start)

Comment: The `sudo` is the problem - X has a permissions system and users other than the one who launched the X session aren't allowed to use it by default (otherwise they could do nasty things like run keyloggers in your X session). Also, running X programs from Tomcat seems like an... odd design.

Comment: Well, my application generates off-screen images and not all AWT code is headless compatible. So the X server is running under myself when I start the OS, right? And when I run Tomcat as root, it can't connect to the X server? What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's been quite a while since this questions was posted.
Nevertheless I'm going to provide a solution ,
The solution for this problem is to run android studio without ***SUDO***

So , if you're doing this on the terminal :-

```
sudo ./studio.sh
```

change it to this and it should work .

```
./studio.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by re-installing the XMING driver

Evidently, a windows update removed it.