# Java + PDFBox not working on linux server

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-14.04, pdfbox

I use the library PDFBox(2.0.0) to convert pdf to png in a web app. The librairy works when I'm working locally on Mac OSX 10.10 but not when I deploy my web app on remote server "Ubunto 14.04"

```
docPDF  = PDDocument.load(new File(pathFPdf));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(docPDF);
docPDF.getNumberOfPages();
BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.RGB);                                                  
ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pngPreviewPath, 300);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `pathFPdf`? Is there an error or exception?

Comment: I tested the file (new File(pathFPdf)) exists, no error. Thanks

Comment: exception  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment

Comment: I would give `-Djava.awt.headless=true` a try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34480/exception-on-desktopsic-sun-awt-x11graphicsenvironment

Comment: But PDFRenderer does use awt, so I wonder if this will work. Btw you're not checking the result of ImageIOUtil.writeImage.

Comment: Thanks. I changed -Djava.awt.headless=true... I have new exception : 
java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':1.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved

I use this parameter in tomcat startup bash : 
export DISPLAY=:0
-Djava.awt.headless=true

[Java Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t)

Thanks!!