# calculating string width java 1.4

Tags: java, fonts

I have java 1.4 application that is running on server.
I need to calculate the width of strings before I create pdf files that include them.
When running the app locally (on my pc) it is o.k. , but when I run it on a server I get an error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY
variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:77)
        at java.lang.Class.forName1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:142)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:72)
        at java.awt.Font.initializeFont(Font.java:285)
        at java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:319)
```

the code that create the problem calculate the width of a string as follows :

```
 protected static String mCutStr(String iText , int iWidthPt , int iEstimatedNumOfChars)
  {
      iWidthPt = iWidthPt-4; //remove padding

      AffineTransform affinetransform = new AffineTransform();     
      FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(affinetransform,true,true);     
      Font font = new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 9);
      int textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(iText, frc).getWidth());
    //  System.out.println("iText="+iText+";    textwidth = "+textwidth+"   iWidthPt ="+iWidthPt);
      if(textwidth <= iWidthPt)
          return iText;
      String vTestStr = iText.substring(0 , iEstimatedNumOfChars)+">>";
      textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(vTestStr, frc).getWidth());
      while(textwidth < iWidthPt)
      {
          iEstimatedNumOfChars++;
          vTestStr = iText.substring(0 , iEstimatedNumOfChars)+">>";
          textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(vTestStr, frc).getWidth());
    //    System.out.println("vTestStr="+vTestStr+"    textwidth = "+textwidth);
      }
      vTestStr = iText.substring(0 , iEstimatedNumOfChars-1)+">>";
      return vTestStr;
  }
```

Is there an other way to calc this without using AWT? 
(it must support minimum java 5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your server in headless mode. Headless mode is useful when actual Window system like X server is not available and you need to perform some AWT related functions.

[Java Documentation about Headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)

If you are using web server like tomcat search how to execute that specific server in headless mode

OR
set system environment property `java.awt.headless` to `true`