# Executing .jar program in Raspberry pi3 from windows remote desktop

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, remote-desktop

I have created a GUI program in java that executes a bunch of commands in the terminal of a raspbian( linux based raspberry pi3 operating system). 
the program works fine if i run it directly(as in not from remote desktop), but when I try to run the program from a remote desktop I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getSystemMnemonicKeyMask(SwingUtilities2.java:2020)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:1158)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:431)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:148)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1577)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:539)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:579)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1349)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1459)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1426)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels(UIManager.java:419)
    at ControlProgram.main(ControlProgram.java:419)
```

the command I use to execute the program is:

```
sudo java -jar /home/pi/Desktop/ControlProgram.jar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t)

Comment: What did your research indicate about what the Exception might tell you?