# java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, x11-forwarding

I have been trying to run a **Java AWT based application on an Ubuntu VM inside Docker**. The application is a very simple one and it flawlessly runs on Windows through Eclipse. It simply opens up a window and prints hello world!. In fact when I export the jar file in to an Ubuntu VM that is running on my Windows host also gives me the same output as Windows when I run the jar file through **“java -jar JFrameDocker.jar”**.

However the story is not same when I try to run it inside docker. The instructions that I have specified in the Dockerfile executes without any error but when I run the application it throws 
**“java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable”** . Trust me guys, I have tried many a times to resolve it but no luck till now.
Like setting the DISPLAY variable value multiple times, starting X server using xterm and xeyes, going through every possible article that I found on the Web. But nothing seems to be working here. I am providing all my files here that could get you a better understanding of my problem. 
By the way [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t) doesn't answer my question as same error is being thrown even after making the changes.

**This is my java file.**

```
package com.etp;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrameDockerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel lable = new JLabel("Hello World");
        panel.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );  
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(lable);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
    }

}
```

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM java:8
ENV DISPLAY :0
ADD JFrameDocker.jar JFrameDocker.jar
CMD ["java","-jar", "JFrameDocker.jar"]
```

I have used below docker commands to build image and run it.

Docker Build :  `sudo docker build -t jframedocker .`

Docker Run : `sudo docker run jframedocker`

[Output Without Error Screenshot: (Without Docker)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTywq.png)

**Output with Docker:**

```
etp@etp-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/JFrameDocker$ sudo docker run jframedocker
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:475)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at com.etp.JFrameDockerTest.main(JFrameDockerTest.java:12)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t)

Comment: Similar thing is discussed in above URL.

Comment: I tried with that one but that couldn't get the solved. That led me to post the question with simple example

Answer (score 3):

You are using `java:8` base image which most likely doesn't provide a graphical environment.

You can use `ubuntu:18.04` base image with manually installed `openjdk-11-jdk` and `xvfb` packages. The [`xvfb-run`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xvfb-run.1.html) command will take care of setting up the virtual X Server environment:

> **xvfb-run**  sets  up  an X authority file (or uses an existing user-specified one), writes a cookie to it (see xauth(1x)) and then starts the Xvfb X server as  a  background  process. The  process  ID of Xvfb is stored for later use.  The specified command is then run using the X display corresponding to the Xvfb server just  started  and  the  X  authority  file created earlier.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk xvfb 
ADD JFrameDocker.java MANIFEST.mf ./
RUN javac JFrameDocker.java
RUN jar cfm JFrameDocker.jar MANIFEST.mf JFrameDocker.class 
RUN xvfb-run java -jar JFrameDocker.jar
```

**JFrameDocker.java**

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrameDocker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel lable = new JLabel("Hello World");
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(lable);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Up and running");
    }

}
```

**MANIFEST.mf**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JFrameDocker
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but that led to following error docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: @SoumyaranjanPani check out the example `Dockerfile`

Comment: I tried with above Dockerfile, but it gets stuck at **"RUN xvfb-run java -jar JFrameDocker.jar"** this step.

Comment: @SoumyaranjanPani it's not stuck, it's running the `JFrame` example you have provided. There is no `AWTError` or `HeadlessException` so the X server and java are configured correctly.

Comment: If it's running then why am I unable to see the JFrame window that prints Hello World!(I have shared an output image with the question )

Comment: @SoumyaranjanPani because it's running in the container, and not in the host system. You would have to configure X forwarding to see the container screen.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Can you please guide me on how to configure X forwarding so that I can see the output in container screen.

Comment: In fact I configured X11 forwarding inside **ssh_config** and **sshd_config** files but still couldn't able to see the output also even it does not print the statement System.out.println("Up and running");

Comment: There are three parameters regarding X11 forwarding inside **ssh_config** and I have set the value as below 
  **ForwardAgent yes**
  **ForwardX11 yes**
  **ForwardX11Trusted yes**

and in **sshd_config**

**X11Forwarding yes**
**X11UseForwarding yes**
**X11DisplayOffset 10**
**X11UseLocalhost yes**